# SMARTY: Variable inside variable

Tags: prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7, smarty3

Is it possible to use a variable inside smarty?

EX: {assign var="delivery_country" value=$customer.addresses.{$delivery_id}.country}}

As you can see i've added {$delivery_id} inside {$customer.addresses.country}

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

```
{assign var="delivery_country" value={$customer.addresses.{$delivery_id}.country}}
```